# How do we determine the boundaries to three constants in a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{equation}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -2 & 5\\ 
4 & -5 & 8\\ 
-3 & 3 & -3\\
\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
b_1\\ 
b_2\\ 
b_3\\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

I need to determine the values of the b constants that would guarantee that the linear system is consistent. I tried to find the inverse of the matrix on the left hand side so that I could try and solve for the $x$ variables and see if there are any values of $b$ that would cause the system to be  inconsistent but the matrix is singular. I then went on to put the matrix in reduced row echelon form.
\begin{equation}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3\\
0 & 1 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}\end{equation}
From this I was able to derive the equations:
$x_1-3x_3=b_1$, $x_2-4x_3=b_2$, and $0=b_3$. I know that the answer is $b_1=b_2+b_3$, but I don't know how to get that with the given information.

Comment: Look! the first row of the matrix is the sum of the second and third...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do Gaussian elimination to reduce the matrix to its row echelon form, you should include the vector b in it. So the same operations will be done on b.

Comment: I didn't understand how we could justify doing that at first, but I was able to understand your answer by recognizing that I'm essentially performing left multiplication upon the matrix with elementary matrices, and therefore I need to do that to both sides of the equation.

Comment: Or think about it this way: you are doing some manipulation on the equations. For example, you multiplied the first equation by 4, then subtract it from the second equation. When you do that, you cannot ignore the right hand side, which will change your solution set.